# SQL Server 2014 Using DateAdd in where clause to filter huge table

Tags: sql, sql-server, where-clause, dateadd

I have two tables `Meter` and `MeterSpot`. `Meter` table has about 9000 records and `MeterSpot` has about 70 million records. `MeterID` column creates the relationship between two tables. This is part of the table design:

- `Meter` : MeterID int, ContractHour int, etc......
- `MeterSpot` : MeterSpotID int, MeterID int, RecordStamp datetime, VolumeToday float etc......

I have a clustered index on `Meter.MeterID` and `MeterSpot.MeterSpotID` and non-clustered index on `MeterSpot.RecordStamp` and `MeterSpot.MeterID`.

Now I need to query data from these two tables and get `MeterID`, `ContractDate` and `VolumeToday` columns for which `ContractDate` falls between a given date range. `ContractDate` is calculated by subtracting `ContractHour` of `Meter` table from `RecordStamp` of `MeterSpot` table.

This is what I have tried:

```
SELECT  
    M.MeterID, MS.VolumeToday,  
    DATEADD(hour, -(M.ContractHour), MS.RecordStamp) AS 'ContractDate'      
FROM 
    Meter AS M
INNER JOIN  
    MeterSpot AS MS ON M.MeterID = MS.MeterID   
WHERE 
    (DATEADD(hour, -(M.ContractHour), MS.RecordStamp)  
       BETWEEN @StartDate and @EndDate)
```

This query is taking hours to execute. I have searched little and found out that when I add functions on where clause the index is not considered.

I tried below and it was quite fast for smaller date ranges.

```
WHERE MS.RecordStamp BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate)
```

I tried to add `ContractHour` to `@StartDate` and `@EndDate` without subtracting it from `RecordStamp`. Still performance looks the same.

Questions:

1. How can I filter data from calculated column?
2. Is there any better way for me to achieve my task?
3. What are the good practices which I should follow when working with this type of huge tables?

Comment: As a performance issue, I can suggest you to use `LEFT JOIN` and filter not expected null values in `WHERE` part - You can also use your `DATEADD` function over `@StartDate` and `@EndDate` instead of `MS.RecordStamp` ;).

Comment: Check the query execution plan. It will probably give you some hints on how to optimize the query.

Comment: @shA.t I have already tried that. But did not had any luck. Anyway thanks for you input :)

Comment: @wdosanjos Thanks. Good point. I will check execution plan.

Comment: Have you tried an indexed view with a calculated column?

Comment: @WilliamJones I have read about indexed views. It says indexed views are suitable for the tables which are not updated regurlary. If not there will be more performance issues. In my case my MeterSpot table updates very oftenly. Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: How often is 'very oftenly' ...   Could you implement a trigger to maintain the date in the MeterSpot table based on the updated values and the referenced meter ContractHours?  Then you could index it,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could give your date criteria twice, once in a way that informs SQL how it may leverage its indexes to accelerate your query, and again to filter out precisely the rows you need to. Is there some maximum value for ContractHour? If so, then you could do something like this:

```
select ... 
from Meter m 
join MeterSpot ms on m.MeterID = ms.MeterID
where 
     (ms.RecordStamp between @StartDateMinusMaxContractHour and @EndDate)
     and (dateadd(hour, -@m.ContractHour, ms.RecordStamp) between @StartDate and @EndDate)
```

Comment: @gorgy Thank you for your comment. ContractHour is defined for each Meter. So there will be only one value for each meter. Meterspot table have multiple records for each meter.